# DAX Summarize - drops records on group by

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Source Data:**

[image]

DAX:

```
Total Derived = 
VAR selected_min_date =
    MIN ( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR selected_max_date =
    MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR vTable =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            MyTable,
            MyTable[PDate] >= selected_min_date
                && MyTable[PDate] <= selected_max_date
        ),
        MyTable[Gcode],
        MyTable[DerTax]
    )
var result = sumx(vTable, MyTable[DerTax])  

RETURN
    Result
```

I was expecting result as **2644.48**, but is outputting 1322.24

What am doing wrong.

I was same result same as with below sql.

```
Select GCode, 
       sum(DerTax)
from MyTable 
where PDate >= @datemin and PDate <=@datemax
group by GCode
```

Comment: As for the 2nd part (the SQL part), if you're using the same @data parameter for both parts of the equation, then of course it will sum for only one date! The DAX part of the question is very interesting

Comment: @Hila.. updated the SQL part.. :)

Comment: Your formula references `Position_Date`, though this can't be seen in your data sample. Can you include and/or correct?

Comment: Oops.. i was changing the column names .. missed this ... update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've grasped how `SUMMARIZE` works. Since your Gcode and DerTax entries are identical for each of the two rows, your `SUMMARIZE` statement will generate a table comprising just a single row, viz:

| Gcode | DerTax |
| --- | --- |
| Grp01 | 1322.24 |

Instead of passing DerTax as a GroupBy column, you should be passing an *aggregation* of that field:

```
Total Derived: =
VAR selected_min_date =
    MIN( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR selected_max_date =
    MAX( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR vTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            MyTable,
            MyTable[PDate] >= selected_min_date
                && MyTable[PDate] <= selected_max_date
        ),
        MyTable[Gcode],
        "Tax", SUM( MyTable[DerTax] )
    )
VAR result =
    SUMX(
        vTable,
        [Tax]
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: Yes got it working.. found this: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-grouping-data/